how can i take access to test method like AbstractClass.InnerClass.fun
I'm trying to write unit test for Abstract Class Realization and I need to write test for method with path Class.InnerClass.fun. example InClass.b2:
package com.example.kotlin_spring

abstract class AbstractClass (name:String){
    fun a1(): String{
        return "a1"
    }
    protected abstract fun a2(): String

    protected abstract fun InClass.b2(): String

    protected class InClass(){
        fun b1():String{
            return "b1"
        }
    }
}

But I can't take access to it.
The example of tests:
class RealClassTest {

    private val realClass = RealClassForTests("name")

    @Test
    fun a2() {
        val a2 = realClass.a22()
        assert(a2 == "Test1")
    }

    @Test
    fun b2() {
        val b2 = realClass.b22()
        assert(b2=="Test2")
    }
}
private class RealClassForTests(name:String): RealClass(name){
    fun a22() = a2()

    fun b22()=InClass.b2()
}

Please, show me, how can i take access to it?

I found the way to resolve it


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*

class RealClassTest {

    private val realClass = RealClassForTests("name")

    @Test
    fun a2() {
        val a2 = realClass.a22()
        assert(a2 == "Test1")
    }

    @Test
    fun b2() {
        val b2 = realClass.b22()
        assert(b2=="Test2")
    }
}
private class RealClassForTests(name:String): RealClass(name){
    val inClass = InClass()

    fun a22() = a2()

    fun b22()=inClass.b2()
}



now it's work

Yes, since InClass is protected, it is only accessible if you extend the enclosing class. By the way, InClass is not an inner class, it's a nested class. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/nested-classes.html for the difference.
